# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,400,3) (400,400)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, opencv3.0, scikit-image

I am using pyshearlab package to denoise image.The function expects an image shape of equal size.After the code is executed denoising is ok for some images
but some images generates an error like this.
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,400,3) (400,400).
so i i printed the shape of the image using img.size and it gives (400,400,3)

My question is,, is it possible to eliminate the third parameter from the image.
someone please help me.

I am using this for image denoising transformations.There are many toolkits available for image transformations in matlab.Is there any packages to do contourlet denoising,curvelet denoising,bandlet denoising  etc in python.

Comment: I suggest first to understand what the third dimension is about. Ist it RGB information?
In principle you can do image[:, :, 0], image[:, :, 1] and/or image[:, :, 2] to pick arrays of shape (400, 400).

Comment: Is the 1(400,400) image black/white, and the (400,400,3) color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an image array of shape (400, 400, 3) in numpy that means that your image has a height and width of 400x400 and 3 channels.

Most of the time that would be Red, Green and Blue. Your other image with shape (400, 400) only has one channel. So these images won't work together nicely.

You have several options here. It really depends on what your function does with the images and what your output needs to be.

You could split the 3-channel image into separate channels and process them independently.

```
channel1 = image[:, :, 0]
channel2 = image[:, :, 1]
channel3 = image[:, :, 2]
```

And then merge them later

```
image = np.dstack((channel1, channel2, channel3))
```

Or if you are sure that you do not need all channels, in case of a greyscale image f. e. all channels might have the same values, you could drop two and only keep one.

Or you can bump your one channel image up to three channels so that they have the same dimensions (using np.dstack as well).